# Props.array change does not trigger useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React and I am trying to update my list upon changes to the list using `useEffect`.

Background :
I have a list that creates buttons when the list is received from the server. So when the view is available, the list may not be available. So I have used `useEffect` to essentially listen to the changes in the list.

Here is my code snippet:

```
A.js
------
function A() {
this.list = [];
}

function onListUpdate(newList) {
console.log("Set list");
this.list = newList;
}
```

```
Main.js
--------

function Main() {
 const [a, setA] = React.useState(null);
 const connect = () => {
  log.info("Calling client.connect");
  x.connect({
   divId: "x-display"
  }).then((a) => {
   setA(a);
  };

return (
 <B a={a} />
);
```

```
B.js
-----
export default function B (props) {

return (
  <C a={props.a} />
);
}

B.props = {
a: PropTypes.object
}
```

```
C.js
-----
export default function C (props) {
const [list, setList] = React.useState([{...props.a.list}]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Called use effect");
  setList(props.a.list);
 }, [props.a]);

return (
<div>
 {list.filter(l => l.view === true).map((l) => {
     <Button imgSrc="icong.png" />                                 
 }
)}
</div>
);
}

C.props = {
a: PropTypes.object
}
```

So `Set list` log line gets printed when the list is recvd from server but the `called use effect` is not printed and neither are the button created.

Kindly let me know what needs to be done. TIA

Comment: It is anti-pattern in React to store/save passed props into local state. Just consume `props.a.list` directly in the child component, then you won't even need to worry about "listening" for changes on the prop value as any changes to props will trigger a rerender anyway. If this isn't clear enough for you or you need further help, then perhaps a more concrete [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what your code is trying to do is in order.

Comment: Do you mean like adding `<div key={ props.a.list } >` ?

Comment: No, I meant something more like `{props.a.list.filter(l => l.view).map((l) => <Button imgSrc="icong.png" />)}`.

Comment: That is not working either. I have updated the qs with more code.

Comment: Are `A` and `Main` sort of the "same component"? What isn't updating the `a` prop as you expect? Or what is this `list` that is supposedly being updated? You've not really shared anything that is complete and/or reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Called use effect");
  setList(props.a.list);
 }, [props.a]);
```

Here the useEffect callback will be triggered only when the whole props.a object changes, it'll not be called when props.a.list is changed. The object comparison will happen by reference, not by value. Try changing the dependency to props.a.list

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Called use effect");
  setList(props.a.list);
 }, [props.a.list]);
```

PS: If it doesn't help include the code for how the list is passed to B component. We'll debug from there.

Comment: I have updated how the list is potentially passed. I tried what you have suggested but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hyoyin_kyuoma Your state is available in the Main component.  Who is calling this onListUpdate, what does this refer in that method. If at all your useEffect method with props.a.list as dependency has to be called, setA method should be called to update the state A. I see that this connect method is doing that but its not called anywhere in the sample you provided. 

Above code is not wholesome enough to triage the actual issue. Probably share a stackblitz or codepen link of your experiment.